# Verify if the url in the Cell A contains the domain in Cell B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table with 2 columns, the first contains an url, the second a domain.

ie:

```
URL                             | Domain
https://example.com/test        | https://example.com/
https://anotherdomain.com/test  | https://example.com/
```

Now i want to add a column, and if the urls in the first column contains the domain of the second column, i need to return "same domain", otherwise "other domain"

ie:

```
URL                             | Domain                | Matches  
https://example.com/test        | https://example.com/  | same domain
https://anotherdomain.com/test  | https://example.com/  | other domain
```

I tried already a few functions like IF, SEARCH and IFERROR, but i can't make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B2,A2)),"Same","Other")
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2;"*"&B2&"*")=0;"Other";"Same")
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, nice. You could remove the `=0` and then swap other and same around